# Maven build failure with identical extension and classifier ('jar', 'null') error

Tags: java

I am creating simple jar like app.jar with following build.gradle

```
jar{
    from{
        configurations.runtimeClasspath.collect {it.isDirectory() ? it : zipTree(it)}
    }
}

jar {
    archiveFileName = 'app.jar'
}

jar{
    duplicatesStrategy = 'exclude'
}
```

Jar got created successfully but when I tried to publish into nexus getting following error,

```
Execution failed for task ':publishMavenPublicationToMavenRepository'.
> Failed to publish publication 'maven' to repository 'maven'
> Invalid publication 'maven': multiple artifacts with the identical extension and classifier ('jar', 'null').
```

I have checked inside the build/libs/ - having only app.jar, no multiple artifacts were created.
Please guide me if you were faced any issues similar.

Comment: That script seems Gradle, not Maven. Also that seems unrelated to the publishing task. Please explain and provide a minimal reproducible example.

Comment: This is the option which I used - https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/publishing_maven.html#publishing_maven